# Grouping records per week in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a query to pull records per week in a year.

COuld you help create a query?.

I am using 2008 SQL.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: There is no such thing as "2008 SQL". Do you mean "SQL Server 2008"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to aggregate results by week in a single year, then aggregate and group with

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, <yourDate>), DATEPART(mm, <yourDate>)
```